# Flutter widgets are not showing any thing

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test, flutter-widget, flutter-container

I'm working on an assignment and my Flutter app suppose to show Text and FontAwesome's Fonts. But widgets are not showing anything and the Android Studio also showing no error and no exceptions..Here is my displaying class code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'icon_reuse.dart';
import 'reuseable_card.dart';
import 'constants.dart';

enum Gender{
  male, female,
}

class InputPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InputPageState createState() => _InputPageState();
}

class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {
  Gender selectedGender;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('BMI CALCULATOR'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: ReUseAbleCard(
                    onPress: (){
                      setState(() {
                        selectedGender = Gender.male;
                      });
                    },
                    colour: selectedGender == Gender.male ? kActiveCardColor : kInactiveCardColor,
                    cardIcons:
                        IconReuse(icons: FontAwesomeIcons.mars, gender: 'MALE'),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ReUseAbleCard(
                    onPress: (){
                      setState(() {
                        selectedGender = Gender.female;
                      });
                    },
                    colour: selectedGender == Gender.female? kActiveCardColor: kInactiveCardColor,
                    cardIcons: IconReuse(
                        icons: FontAwesomeIcons.venus, gender: 'FEMALE'),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
 Container(
            color: kBottomCardColor,
            height: kBottomCardHeight,
            width: double.infinity,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and my reuseable_card class is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ReUseAbleCard extends StatelessWidget {
  ReUseAbleCard({@required this.colour, this.cardIcons,this.onPress});

  final Widget cardIcons;
  final Color colour;
  final Function onPress;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPress,
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: colour,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and icon_class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'constants.dart';

class IconReuse extends StatelessWidget {
  IconReuse({ this.icons, this.gender});
  final IconData icons;
  final String gender;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(
            icons,
            size: 80,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10.0,
          ),
          Text(
            gender,
            style: kTextLabelStyle,
          ),
        ],
    );
  }
}
```

and the constant class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const kActiveCardColor = Color(0xFF1D1E33);
const kInactiveCardColor = Color(0xFF111328);
const kBottomCardColor = Color(0xFFEB1555);
const kBottomCardHeight = 80.0;


const kTextLabelStyle = TextStyle(
  fontSize: 18.0,
  color: Color(0xFF8D8E98),
);
```

and the main class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'input_page.dart';

void main() => runApp(BMICalculator());

class BMICalculator extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        primaryColor: Color(0xFF0A0E21),
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xFF0A0E21),
      ),
      home: InputPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

**I have add fontAwesome dependencies in pubspec.yaml file..** 
I did **Delete** app many times.
I did **clean the Flutter**
but not understanding what is worng..

Comment: Did you run `flutter packages get` after adding dependencies in `pubspec.yaml` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You forgot to add `cardIcons` as `child` of `Container` 
code snippet

```
return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPress,
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: colour,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
        child: cardIcons,
      ),
    );
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

const kActiveCardColor = Color(0xFF1D1E33);
const kInactiveCardColor = Color(0xFF111328);
const kBottomCardColor = Color(0xFFEB1555);
const kBottomCardHeight = 80.0;

const kTextLabelStyle = TextStyle(
  fontSize: 18.0,
  color: Color(0xFF8D8E98),
);

void main() => runApp(BMICalculator());

class BMICalculator extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        primaryColor: Color(0xFF0A0E21),
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xFF0A0E21),
      ),
      home: InputPage(),
    );
  }
}

class IconReuse extends StatelessWidget {
  IconReuse({this.icons, this.gender});
  final IconData icons;
  final String gender;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Icon(
          icons,
          size: 80,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 10.0,
        ),
        Text(
          gender,
          style: kTextLabelStyle,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class ReUseAbleCard extends StatelessWidget {
  ReUseAbleCard({@required this.colour, this.cardIcons, this.onPress});

  final Widget cardIcons;
  final Color colour;
  final Function onPress;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPress,
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: colour,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
        child: cardIcons,
      ),
    );
  }
}

enum Gender {
  male,
  female,
}

class InputPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InputPageState createState() => _InputPageState();
}

class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {
  Gender selectedGender;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('BMI CALCULATOR'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: ReUseAbleCard(
                    onPress: () {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedGender = Gender.male;
                      });
                    },
                    colour: selectedGender == Gender.male
                        ? kActiveCardColor
                        : kInactiveCardColor,
                    cardIcons:
                        IconReuse(icons: FontAwesomeIcons.mars, gender: 'MALE'),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ReUseAbleCard(
                    onPress: () {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedGender = Gender.female;
                      });
                    },
                    colour: selectedGender == Gender.female
                        ? kActiveCardColor
                        : kInactiveCardColor,
                    cardIcons: IconReuse(
                        icons: FontAwesomeIcons.venus, gender: 'FEMALE'),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            color: kBottomCardColor,
            height: kBottomCardHeight,
            width: double.infinity,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it helps you. thanks.